# What's the simplest way to execute plain Javascript in a React .js file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What's the simplest way to execute plain Javascript in a React 16 .js file?

Below is a render block from a React file (call it myfile.js; entire file is below).

How can I get, i.e.

`console.log;`

or i.e.,

`var timestamp = Math.round((new Date()).getTime() / 1000);`

(or other plain Javascript) to execute?

Do I need to use `const`?

Is it better to use the bulk of Javascript outside of the render block?

```
 render () {
    const { columns, children, singleColumn, isModalOpen } = this.props;
    const { renderComposePanel } = this.state;

    if (singleColumn) {
      return (
        <div className='columns-area__panels'>
          <div className='columns-area__panels__pane columns-area__panels__pane--compositional'>
            <div className='columns-area__panels__pane__inner'>
              {renderComposePanel && <ComposePanel />}
            </div>
          </div>

          <div className='columns-area__panels__main'>
            <div className='tabs-bar__wrapper'><div id='tabs-bar__portal' />



            console.log('Hello World'');  // execute plain JS here
            var timestamp = Math.round((new Date()).getTime() / 1000);


            
            </div>
            <div className='columns-area columns-area--mobile'>{children}</div>
          </div>

          <div className='columns-area__panels__pane columns-area__panels__pane--start columns-area__panels__pane--navigational'>
            <div className='columns-area__panels__pane__inner'>
              <NavigationPanel />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }

    return (
      <div className={`columns-area ${ isModalOpen ? 'unscrollable' : '' }`} ref={this.setRef}>
        {columns.map(column => {
          const params = column.get('params', null) === null ? null : column.get('params').toJS();
          const other  = params && params.other ? params.other : {};

          return (
            <BundleContainer key={column.get('uuid')} fetchComponent={componentMap[column.get('id')]} loading={this.renderLoading(column.get('id'))} error={this.renderError}>
              {SpecificComponent => <SpecificComponent columnId={column.get('uuid')} params={params} multiColumn {...other} />}
            </BundleContainer>
          );
        })}

        {React.Children.map(children, child => React.cloneElement(child, { multiColumn: true }))}
      </div>
    );
  }

}
```

Entire `myfile.js` :

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import ImmutablePropTypes from 'react-immutable-proptypes';
import ImmutablePureComponent from 'react-immutable-pure-component';
import BundleContainer from '../containers/bundle_container';
import ColumnLoading from './column_loading';
import DrawerLoading from './drawer_loading';
import BundleColumnError from './bundle_column_error';
import {
  Compose,
  Notifications,
  HomeTimeline,
  CommunityTimeline,
  PublicTimeline,
  HashtagTimeline,
  DirectTimeline,
  FavouritedStatuses,
  BookmarkedStatuses,
  ListTimeline,
  Directory,
} from '../../ui/util/async-components';
import ComposePanel from './compose_panel';
import NavigationPanel from './navigation_panel';
import { supportsPassiveEvents } from 'detect-passive-events';
import { scrollRight } from '../../../scroll';

const componentMap = {
  'COMPOSE': Compose,
  'HOME': HomeTimeline,
  'NOTIFICATIONS': Notifications,
  'PUBLIC': PublicTimeline,
  'REMOTE': PublicTimeline,
  'COMMUNITY': CommunityTimeline,
  'HASHTAG': HashtagTimeline,
  'DIRECT': DirectTimeline,
  'FAVOURITES': FavouritedStatuses,
  'BOOKMARKS': BookmarkedStatuses,
  'LIST': ListTimeline,
  'DIRECTORY': Directory,
};

export default class ColumnsArea extends ImmutablePureComponent {

  static contextTypes = {
    router: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  };

  static propTypes = {
    columns: ImmutablePropTypes.list.isRequired,
    isModalOpen: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
    singleColumn: PropTypes.bool,
    children: PropTypes.node,
  };

  // Corresponds to (max-width: $no-gap-breakpoint + 285px - 1px) in SCSS
  mediaQuery = 'matchMedia' in window && window.matchMedia('(max-width: 1174px)');

  state = {
    renderComposePanel: !(this.mediaQuery && this.mediaQuery.matches),
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    if (!this.props.singleColumn) {
      this.node.addEventListener('wheel', this.handleWheel, supportsPassiveEvents ? { passive: true } : false);
    }

    if (this.mediaQuery) {
      if (this.mediaQuery.addEventListener) {
        this.mediaQuery.addEventListener('change', this.handleLayoutChange);
      } else {
        this.mediaQuery.addListener(this.handleLayoutChange);
      }
      this.setState({ renderComposePanel: !this.mediaQuery.matches });
    }

    this.isRtlLayout = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].classList.contains('rtl');
  }

  componentWillUpdate(nextProps) {
    if (this.props.singleColumn !== nextProps.singleColumn && nextProps.singleColumn) {
      this.node.removeEventListener('wheel', this.handleWheel);
    }
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (this.props.singleColumn !== prevProps.singleColumn && !this.props.singleColumn) {
      this.node.addEventListener('wheel', this.handleWheel, supportsPassiveEvents ? { passive: true } : false);
    }
  }

  componentWillUnmount () {
    if (!this.props.singleColumn) {
      this.node.removeEventListener('wheel', this.handleWheel);
    }

    if (this.mediaQuery) {
      if (this.mediaQuery.removeEventListener) {
        this.mediaQuery.removeEventListener('change', this.handleLayoutChange);
      } else {
        this.mediaQuery.removeListener(this.handleLayouteChange);
      }
    }
  }

  handleChildrenContentChange() {
    if (!this.props.singleColumn) {
      const modifier = this.isRtlLayout ? -1 : 1;
      this._interruptScrollAnimation = scrollRight(this.node, (this.node.scrollWidth - window.innerWidth) * modifier);
    }
  }

  handleLayoutChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({ renderComposePanel: !e.matches });
  }

  handleWheel = () => {
    if (typeof this._interruptScrollAnimation !== 'function') {
      return;
    }

    this._interruptScrollAnimation();
  }

  setRef = (node) => {
    this.node = node;
  }

  renderLoading = columnId => () => {
    return columnId === 'COMPOSE' ? <DrawerLoading /> : <ColumnLoading multiColumn />;
  }

  renderError = (props) => {
    return <BundleColumnError multiColumn errorType='network' {...props} />;
  }

  render () {
    const { columns, children, singleColumn, isModalOpen } = this.props;
    const { renderComposePanel } = this.state;

    if (singleColumn) {
      return (
        <div className='columns-area__panels'>
          <div className='columns-area__panels__pane columns-area__panels__pane--compositional'>
            <div className='columns-area__panels__pane__inner'>
              {renderComposePanel && <ComposePanel />}
            </div>
          </div>

          <div className='columns-area__panels__main'>
            <div className='tabs-bar__wrapper'><div id='tabs-bar__portal' /></div>
            <div className='columns-area columns-area--mobile'>{children}</div>
          </div>

          <div className='columns-area__panels__pane columns-area__panels__pane--start columns-area__panels__pane--navigational'>
            <div className='columns-area__panels__pane__inner'>
              <NavigationPanel />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }

    return (
      <div className={`columns-area ${ isModalOpen ? 'unscrollable' : '' }`} ref={this.setRef}>
        {columns.map(column => {
          const params = column.get('params', null) === null ? null : column.get('params').toJS();
          const other  = params && params.other ? params.other : {};

          return (
            <BundleContainer key={column.get('uuid')} fetchComponent={componentMap[column.get('id')]} loading={this.renderLoading(column.get('id'))} error={this.renderError}>
              {SpecificComponent => <SpecificComponent columnId={column.get('uuid')} params={params} multiColumn {...other} />}
            </BundleContainer>
          );
        })}

        {React.Children.map(children, child => React.cloneElement(child, { multiColumn: true }))}
      </div>
    );
  }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding `console.log` into the function?

Comment: @LajosArpad Thanks, but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: @RandyCasburn Thanks, I'm new to React but know a little Javascript. Is an expression like this: `{ 'hello' + 'world'; }` ?  Or (maybe this is a different question) would I be better off adding my Javascript to an external file and loading it?

Comment: I did; but most of my experience is with jQuery.

Comment: @BlueDogRanch **Why** do you want to do this?

Comment: @DaveNewton Thanks :) Using Javascript, I want to show one or another HTML div depending on the current date. I was using jQuery, but was having problems with getting that to work consistently, I think because of React's DOM.

Comment: @BlueDogRanch How about doing this code before the `return`, storing the result in a variable and just putting the `{variable}` in the JSX? Yes, there are other ways, that do exactly what you're asking for, like IIFEs, regular function, function component, but imo. a variable is the simplest and cleanest solution.

Comment: @BlueDogRanch take a look at my provided snippet. Which goes over `useState`, `useContext` and a basic parent/child component provider/consumer structure --- It also uses a simple `log()` hook that `console.log`s contents + a timestamp. I don't know your use-case or who would downvote a very simple working example - provide your own examples and help people learn.

Comment: @Thomas Thanks, I hadn't thought of that; I'm new to React.

Comment: @BlueDogRanch You mean conditional rendering?

Comment: @WesleyLeMahieu Thanks! I'll look at your answer; it looks more complex than I need. I want to show one or another HTML div depending on the current date as determined by Javascript.

Comment: @DaveNewton In a sense, yes, using Javascript `new Date();` and < and > operators with fixed dates. I.e., to show one HTML div on Monday, another on Tuesday, etc.

Comment: @Thomas Can you do an example of that?

Comment: @BlueDogRanch My point was that “reactjs conditional rendering” can be searched. That said, I’d consider pulling the bulk of it out of the render, which is already pretty bulky. Unrelated but it looks like you’re duplicating existing routing solutions.

Comment: @DaveNewton Thanks, I know very little React, and this is not my code; I'm just trying to add a feature in plain Javascript.

Comment: @BlueDogRanch I provided a simple example of what Dave is speaking of. It shows a different div based on the day.

Comment: @RandyCasburn You can call `console.log` just fine in JSX. Like `<Example test={console.log(…)}>{console.log(…)}</Example>`. Sure, this isn't very useful as it'll render `undefined`, but you can easily call other functions that do stuff (including logging) and return values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what works in a simple React App. I moved the plain Javascript out of the render and return blocks to the top of the file (under the import calls), and then used 1) either `const` for the variable `timestampone`. Or, 2) for a Javascript variable with HTML, `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`, which is OK for me, as no one will have access to insert HTML other than me.

**App.js:**

```
    import * as React from 'react';

    const timestampone = <span> {Math.round((new Date()).getTime() / 1000)} </span>;
    
    var timestamptwo = Math.round((new Date()).getTime() / 1000);
    if (timestamptwo >=1675893600 && timestamptwo <= 1675897200 ) {
    var timedate = '<div class="wrapper">Between Timestamps</div>';
    }
    
    function App() {
    
    return (
    
    <div className="App">

         timestampone: {timestampone}
    
         <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: timedate}} />
    
   </div>

      );
    }
    
    export default App;
```

Answer (score -1):

In your situation, there's two simple ways to do it:

By creating your function immediately inside your `render` block, then executing the function within the HTML using `{}` to wrap variable:

```
render () {
  const runJavascript = () => {
    console.log('Hello World'');  // execute plain JS here
    var timestamp = Math.round((new Date()).getTime() / 1000);
  };

  if (singleColumn) {
    return (
      <div>{runJavascript()}</div>
    );
  }

  return <div>hello world</div>;
}
```

Additionally, you can create your `runJavascript` function *outside* of your render block along-side any `constructor`, `componentDidMount` or `componentDidUnmount` blocks you may have:

```
runJavascript = () => {
  console.log('Hello World'');  // execute plain JS here
  var timestamp = Math.round((new Date()).getTime() / 1000);
};

render () {
  if (singleColumn) {
    return (
      <div>{this.runJavascript()}</div>
    );
  }

  return <div>hello world</div>;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That's interesting. So does the `const` block go outside the render block? And I use `<div id="root"></div>` inside the render block?

Comment: In React, the entire `App` is initially rendered using `ReactDOM` and a simple JS selector. That's the only time you'll ever see that render --- Then you have your `App` which you can think of as the root of your app/site. App, Sunday and Monday are all `React functional components`. As such, each must `return` one parent body of `JSX`. So in this example, when the app loads, it checks what today is, and renders a different component based on that. `return null` will just show nothing - a white page --- https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started

Comment: The React code I posted is currently part of an app (not mine), and I don't know React at all. So the day of the week is output in `<div id="root"></div>`?

Comment: `App` component is placed inside `<div id="root"></div>`, yep! That's how all React apps are "mounted" or "initialized". The one piece of pure-javascript code was `document.getElementById('root')`. The rest is `React`.

Comment: Thanks, this is interesting, but I would like to see how to run Javascript right in the file.

Comment: That's fairly vague - You can run Javascript anywhere within React. There can be issues if you are trying to retain state, which is why things like `useState` are incredibly important --- `const timestamp = new Date().getDay();` this is running javascript right in the file. If you mean trying to do this: `return (<div>{const timestamp = new Date().getDay(); console.log(timestamp);}</div>)`, then that's not really a thing. I'd recommend brushing up on all the React `Get Started` tutorials --- Good luck!

Comment: Ok, but how exactly do I use your answer in myfile.js? I'm putting the const block outside of the render block, but get Unexpected token at `const Monday = () => {...`

Comment: https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html

Comment: Added an example for you in case you need it.

Comment: Thanks! I'll still try the React solution, but right now, for the first Javascript example, I get "TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null", so there's a problem with the code running before DOM completes, I guess; and the second example throws an "assignment to undeclared variable runJavascript" error, so  guess I need to declare "runJavascript"?